# How to set a different state's variable for each children inside loop Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following problem with state usage on below code snippet.

```html
<div class="featured-card-container">
  <swiper class="swiper" :options="swiperOption">
    <template v-for="(strategy, index) in strategiesCards">
      <swiper-slide :key="'slider-' + index">
        <strategy-card
          :data="strategy"
          @click.native="showModalStrategies()"
        />
      </swiper-slide>
      <strategies-modal
        :key="'modal-' + index"
        :dialog.sync="modalStrategies"
        :data="strategy"
      />
    </template>
    <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

So basically, all I need to is triggering a modal from its responsible card. I just kind of having a hard time how to settle this.
My current approach is the above code.

But I know the problem would come that, the `modalStrategies` data state is being used by many components. So it makes them like quickly changing all the existing modal even I clicked only one card.

How I can I fixed this? Is there any workaround?

Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate your effort to try understanding my problems.

Comment: I forgot to tell you guys that this already fixed guys! Thanks! No need to worry.

Comment: If it's fixed, can you add the answer for others to learn? (Or remove the question if you think it's unnecessary?)

Comment: @nbixler ah, thats a good idea. Let me write the approach that I made later.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template v-for="(strategy, index) in strategiesCards">
    <swiper-slide :key="'slider-' + index">
        <strategy-card
            :data="strategy"
            @click.native="showModalStrategies(strategy)"
        />
    </swiper-slide>
    <strategies-modal
        :key="'modal-' + index"
        :dialog.sync="isShowModal"
        :data="strategy"
    />
</template>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        modalStrategy: null,
        currentStrategy: null
    }
},
computed: {
    isShowModal: {
        get() {
            return this.modalStrategy === this.currentStrategy
        },
        // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier
        set(val) {
            if(!val) {
                this.modalStrategy = null
            }
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    showModalStrategies(strategy) {
        this.currentStrategy= strategy
        this.modalStrategy = strategy
    }
}
```